# Select Mutual Followers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, social-networking

I know this has many questions here but no answer I've found works for me. I'm building a social network and I'm working on the user list page. In my database are two tables, `users` & `followers`. The `id` column in the `users` table is a foreign key in the `followers` table whose columns are `id`, `user_id` & `follower_id`. The `follower_id` is the user id of the user who followed the `user_id` user.

When showing the list of all users on the social network I want to exclude:
    1)The users being followed by the `logged_in_user`
    2)The users following the `logged_in_user`

When showing the list of all users I also want to prioritize any mutual followers to be displayed first.

This are my current queries (`$userid` refers to the `logged_in_user` and `$start` is an integer sent when the user loads more users)

```
<?

//list of users following the `logged_in_user`
$followers = $db->query(
        'SELECT followers.id, followers.user_id, followers.follower_id, users.id, users.username, users.profileimg 
        FROM followers, users 
        WHERE followers.user_id=:userid 
        AND followers.follower_id=users.id 
        LIMIT 8 OFFSET '.$start.';', array(':userid'=>$userid));

//list of users being followed by the `logged_in_user`
$following = $db->query(
        'SELECT followers.id, followers.user_id, followers.follower_id, users.id, users.username, users.profileimg 
        FROM followers, users 
        WHERE followers.follower_id=:userid 
        AND followers.user_id=users.id 
        LIMIT 8 OFFSET '.$start.';', array(':userid'=>$userid));

//list of all users: here I excluded the `logged_in_user`
$users = $db->query(
        'SELECT users.id, users.username, users.profileimg, users.gender, users.last_seen 
        FROM users 
        WHERE users.id!=:userid 
        LIMIT 8 OFFSET '.$start.';', array(':userid'=>$userid));

?>
```

Could anyone help me tie these three queries together to get the desired result: A list of all users who are following/being followed by the users who are following/being followed by the `logged_in_user` i.e mutual followers. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I have found some code to help me remove the users following/being followed by `logged_in_user`

```html
<?

//remove followers from list of users
foreach ($followers as $fr) {
 foreach($users as $elementKey => $element) {
     foreach($element as $valueKey => $value) {
         if($valueKey == 'username' && $value == $fr['username']){
             //delete this particular object from the $users
             unset($users[$elementKey]);
         } 
     }
 }
}

//remove users following logged_in_user from list of users
foreach ($following as $fg) {
 foreach($users as $elementKey => $element) {
     foreach($element as $valueKey => $value) {
         if($valueKey == 'username' && $value == $fg['username']){
             //delete this particular object from the $users
             unset($users[$elementKey]);
         } 
     }
 }
}
?>
```

All I need now is to fetch all users whose `id` matches the `follower_id` column in the `followers` table because their corresponding `user_id` column will be the mutual followers between the `logged_in_user` and the users followed/following him/her.

Comment: Please, don't bind *some* of your parameters, bind **all** of them. `$start` is a huge liability here being introduced without escaping.

Comment: yes i intend to do that, just needed a separate query for mutual users between logged_in_user and followers/following

Comment: It's also a bad habit of putting `;` at the end of queries run through code like this. That delimiter is only necessary when using an interactive MySQL shell or when defining stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did next after the update above was run another query that fetched the desired users.

```html
<?

foreach ($users as $ur) {
 $user_id = $ur['id'];
 $mutual[]= $db->query('SELECT followers.id, followers.user_id, followers.follower_id, users.id, users.username, users.profileimg FROM followers, users WHERE followers.follower_id=:userid AND followers.user_id=users.id LIMIT 100 OFFSET '.$start.';', array(':userid'=>$user_id));
}

echo json_encode($mutual);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

If it was me, I'd start with something like this (including DDLs of same)...

```
1 Romeo
2 Juliet
3 Benvolio
4 Mercutio
5 Tybalt

user follows
   5       2
   4       1
   4       2
   1       3
```

...and instead ask, what query can tell us who else is following/being followed by the individuals following/being followed by Romeo.

Comment: hey yeah that's better worded. Thank you.